Spark SQL XML Parsing
I am trying to parse XML and extract node value within XML using Spark-SQL ,
Consider below XML
<Account><ID1><other><ID>123</ID></other></ID1></Account>

Here I am trying to extract 123 using XPath but not getting expected Result.
I appreciated any help here.

Are u using azure databricks?

Yes , I am using Azure data bricks. Trying to do this with Spark- SQL since we have one column in table which has XML data.

to parse XML and extract node values in azure databricks using spark sql, you can use xpath_string function. example:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("XML Parsing with Spark SQL") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Sample data with XML content
data = [
    ('<Account><ID1><other><ID>123</ID></other></ID1></Account>',),
    ('<Account><ID1><other><ID>456</ID></other></ID1></Account>',)
]

# Define column names
columns = ['xml_data']

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Show the DataFrame content
df.show(truncate=False)

# Register the DataFrame as a temp view
df.createOrReplaceTempView("xml_table")

# Execute SQL query to extract values using XPath
result = spark.sql("""
    SELECT 
        xpath_string(xml_data, 'Account/ID1/other/ID/text()') AS extracted_id 
    FROM 
        xml_table
""")

# Show the results
result.show(truncate=False)

# Stop the Spark session
spark.stop()

output:



extracted_id




123


456



